# Reformatting API Call results in an Atlas. Nominatim and OpenWeatherMap

Tags: qgis, atlas, nominatim, openweathermap-api

I am creating information sheets for geotagged photos using the atlas features in QGIS 3.14. Some of the information is created using a graphical model but I want to add some more using API calls.
I have managed to use HTML frames to present the results of calls to Nominatim and OpenWeatherMap using expressions like the below

```
'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat='||  "latitude"  || '&lon=' || "longitude"  || '&zoom=18&addressdetails=1'
```

This works well but the results contain more information than I need so I would like to be able to re-format them.

```xml
<reversegeocode timestamp="Wed, 07 Apr 21 09:25:16 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="format=xml&lat=88.88&lon=88.88&zoom=18&addressdetails=2">
<result place_id="101970880" osm_type="way" osm_id="46739254" ref="Gypsy Lane" lat="51.6895477895927" lon="-0.43032246110111033" boundingbox="51.6858356,51.69023,-0.4312647,-0.4303209" place_rank="26" address_rank="26">Gypsy Lane, Hunton Bridge, Abbots Langley, Leavesden, Three Rivers, Hertfordshire, East of England, England, WD4 8PS, United Kingdom</result>
<addressparts>
<road>Gypsy Lane</road>
<hamlet>Hunton Bridge</hamlet>
<suburb>Abbots Langley</suburb>
<village>Leavesden</village>
<city>Three Rivers</city>
<county>Hertfordshire</county>
<state_district>East of England</state_district>
<state>England</state>
<postcode>WD4 8PS</postcode>
<country>United Kingdom</country>
<country_code>gb</country_code>
</addressparts>
</reversegeocode>"
```

[image: This is simplified version of What I am doing]
The only strategy I can think of is to try and download an xml for each photo in the graphical model then read the contents into a string and re-format it but that seems clumsy and I probably couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Currently the information is called for and displayed using a HTMl but the output provides more than I need - I have added an image to the question to show what I am doing. I have read up on map_get() but that seems to be used for getting properties of elements on the map frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this custom function:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import urllib.request
import urllib
import json

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def jsonfromurl(url, feature, parent, context):
    header = {"accept":"application/json"}
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    response_data = response.read()
    encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(response_data.decode(encoding))
    #txt = json.dumps(data) #uncomment this line to receive data as string. also change next line to: return txt
    return data
```

and use it basically like this within a textbox:

`map_get(jsonfromurl('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=51.6895477895927&lon=-0.43032246110111033&zoom=18&addressdetails=1'),'address')`

This will return a `map` of the `address` content. You can format it as you like to e.g. by using `map_to_hstore()` or whatever. Or get further contents like only the road by using it like:

`map_get(map_get(jsonfromurl('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=51.6895477895927&lon=-0.43032246110111033&zoom=18&addressdetails=1'),'address'),'road')`

Or just use the `display_name` together with a `substring`, like:

`substr(map_get(jsonfromurl('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=51.6895477895927&lon=-0.43032246110111033&zoom=18&addressdetails=1'),'display_name'),13,29)`

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used custom functions before so I have learnt a lot. I assume you could write a more specific function for nominatim requests that worked directly from the geometry and allowed the user to specify the zoom and address details as paramaters. I have substituted the fixed location with my lat long variables and it works for my atlas.